# R Studio - save all scripts using R command

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

Is there a way to save all scripts using an R command in R Studio?  There is a button with keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+s) which saves all the open scripts that have been modified.

The purpose is so that I can wrap Shiny::runapp() into a function that includes saving all the scripts before it is run.  This would save on all those times when running a Shiny app without saving first - a considerable amount of time for me as I tend to forget!

The function would be like this:

```
runapp2 <- function(){
  save_all_modified_scripts() # <- hope you exist
  Shiny::runapp()
}
```

Update (thanks to Marius) - this is working for me:

```
save_and_run <- function(){
  rstudioapi::documentSaveAll()
  shiny::runApp()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function in the `rstudioapi` package (built in to RStudio):

```
rstudioapi::documentSaveAll()
```

I have not tested it extensively so I'm not sure how well it works, but it does seem to do what's required.